# XLS Create New Element If Condition Meet

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm receiving this error:

> The element type "xsl:if" must be terminated by
>     the matching end-tag ""

when I'm trying to close and open a new `fo:block` if a certain condition is meet.

```
<xsl:if test=".[@pdf_break='true']">
        </fo:block><fo:block>
</xsl:if>
```

How must this be written?

Full example of what I'm trying to do:

```
<fo:block>
<xsl:for-each select="/article/front/article-meta/contrib-group/contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
    <fo:basic-link show-destination="new" external-destination="url({$link})" >
        <fo:inline>&#160;<xsl:value-of select="name/given-names" />&#160;<xsl:value-of select="name/surname" />&#160;<fo:inline font-size="8pt" vertical-align="super" font-family="HelveticaNeueLTCom-Lt_1" padding-right="8pt" padding-left="-8pt"><xsl:for-each select="xref[@ref-type='aff']"><xsl:value-of select="sup" /><xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if></xsl:for-each></fo:inline></fo:inline>
    </fo:basic-link>
    <xsl:if test=".[@pdf_break='true']">
        </fo:block><fo:block>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

so basically it should be:

```
<fo:block>
Some amount of authors listed with links
</fo:block>
```

when pdf_break is never `true`, and then:

```
<fo:block>
Some amount of authors listed with links
</fo:block>
<fo:block>
More authors listed with links
</fo:block>
```

when the attribute is `true`.

Example XML:

```
<contrib-group>
    <contrib equal-contrib="yes" contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surnameExample1</surname>
            <given-names>Example1</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID1'><sup>1</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib equal-contrib="yes" contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example2</surname>
            <given-names>Example2</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID2'><sup>2</sup></xref>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID3'><sup>3</sup></xref>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID4'><sup>4</sup></xref>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID5'><sup>5</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib equal-contrib="yes" contrib-type='author' pdf_break='true'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example3</surname>
            <given-names>Example3</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID2'><sup>2</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example4</surname>
            <given-names>Example4</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID6'><sup>6</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example5</surname>
            <given-names>Example15</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID2'><sup>2</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
</contrib-group>
```

Comment: `</fo:block><fo:block>` is backwards: it needs to be `<fo:block></fo:block>` or `<fo:block/>`.

Comment: That's not possible. An XSLT stylesheet must be also a well-formed XML document. *"A consequence of well-formedness in general entities is that the logical and physical structures in an XML document are properly nested; no start-tag, end-tag, empty-element tag, element, comment, processing instruction, character reference, or entity reference can begin in one entity and end in another."*  https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#wf-entities

Comment: Please show an example of the input - see: [mcve].

Comment: I've added in an example from the `contrib-group` level, if a more parent level is required please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you want to use `for-each-group`, perhaps with `group-adjacent="@pdf_break"` or `group-starting-with="*[@pdf_break = 'true']"`. See the examples in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info or any other introduction on grouping or edit your question and show us the result you want for the input sample have at the end of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
   <doc xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="contrib" group-ending-with="contrib[@pdf_break = 'true']">
      <fo:block>
         <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
           <author><xsl:sequence select="name/surname, name/given-names"/></author>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </fo:block>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </doc>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<contrib-group>
    <contrib equal-contrib="yes" contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example1</surname>
            <given-names>Example1</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID1'><sup>1</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib equal-contrib="yes" contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example2</surname>
            <given-names>Example2</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID2'><sup>2</sup></xref>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID3'><sup>3</sup></xref>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID4'><sup>4</sup></xref>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID5'><sup>5</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib equal-contrib="yes" contrib-type='author' pdf_break='true'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example3</surname>
            <given-names>Example3</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID2'><sup>2</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example4</surname>
            <given-names>Example4</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID6'><sup>6</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
    <contrib contrib-type='author' pdf_break='false'>
        <name>
            <surname>Example5</surname>
            <given-names>Example15</given-names>
        </name>
        <xref ref-type='aff' rid='ID2'><sup>2</sup></xref>
    </contrib>
</contrib-group>
```

**The wanted -structured output is produced:**

```
<doc xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:block>
      <author>
         <surname>Example1</surname>
         <given-names>Example1</given-names>
      </author>
      <author>
         <surname>Example2</surname>
         <given-names>Example2</given-names>
      </author>
      <author>
         <surname>Example3</surname>
         <given-names>Example3</given-names>
      </author>
   </fo:block>
   <fo:block>
      <author>
         <surname>Example4</surname>
         <given-names>Example4</given-names>
      </author>
      <author>
         <surname>Example5</surname>
         <given-names>Example15</given-names>
      </author>
   </fo:block>
</doc>
```

---

**XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kInGroup" match="contrib" 
          use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::contrib[@pdf_break = 'true'][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match=
     "contrib[generate-id()
             = generate-id(key('kInGroup',
                                generate-id(preceding-sibling::contrib[@pdf_break='true']
                                                                                 [1]
                              )
                           )[1]
                         )
             ]">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
      "key('kInGroup',
            generate-id(preceding-sibling::contrib[@pdf_break = 'true'][1])
           )"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="contrib" mode="inGroup">
     <author><xsl:copy-of select="name/*"/></author>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the same XML document (above), again the correct-structured output is produced**:

```
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <author>
      <surname>Example1</surname>
      <given-names>Example1</given-names>
   </author>
   <author>
      <surname>Example2</surname>
      <given-names>Example2</given-names>
   </author>
   <author>
      <surname>Example3</surname>
      <given-names>Example3</given-names>
   </author>
</fo:block>
<fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <author>
      <surname>Example4</surname>
      <given-names>Example4</given-names>
   </author>
   <author>
      <surname>Example5</surname>
      <given-names>Example15</given-names>
   </author>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: @user3783243: Depends on the conditions. You may contact me at: dnovatchev at Gmail

Answer (score 1):

I think, if you have access to XSLT 2 or 3, you can use

```
  <xsl:template match="contrib-group">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="contrib[@contrib-type = 'author']" group-starting-with="*[@pdf_break = 'true']">
          <fo:block>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </fo:block>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEv4/1 is a minimal sample, of course you need to add templates for remaining XML input to XSL-FO transformation.

Comment: Martin, the way I understand the question, it seems that `group-ending-with` must be used -- not `group-starting-with`